Direct transition between hardwood and drywall
I have this direct transition between hardwood flooring and drywall in a closet where I don't feel like investing in a baseboard. Would it be okay if I just put clear caulking to close the horizontal gap (be flush with the hardwood)?
I have done something similar before but the flooring was epoxy so I just drywall mudded the vertical part down to the very corner. But here is different because the flooring edge in detached.


You could use caulk, but it would be wrong. There are reasons that baseboards are used.

Some type of baseboard like covering will probably be best.  Even if just quarter round.  There is also that plastic stuff if wood not wanted.

Trim would aesthetically be the most appealing option, but there is no reason caulking wouldn't work to fill in the edges. If the gaps are overly large, install a backer rod before to bulk fill the area.

The advice here is not good. Flooring as shown has a gap to the wall to allow for seasonal expansion of the flooring material. Without the proper gap the flooring can buckle.

@MichaelKaras Backer rod and caulk both allows seasonal expansion and contraction as far as I've ever read/heard.

While backer rod and caulk is not the right thing to do, I do believe the wood will still be able to expand.

I mean, if you simply must use caulk, I certainly would not use a clear caulk!

Wood flooring needs the gap for expansion.
Do not fill the gap, use Baseboards to cover it while allowing the wood to expand and contact per season temp and humidity.
